# Silverlight - Setting width of inner control based on width of container control

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a peculiar requirement related to setting width of controls in silverlight. Generally when UI renders in Silverlight, width of container control is calculated based on widths of child controls. I have a requirement where layout of the application can change drastically. One of the scenarios is that I have a Grid cotaining listboxes in each column. These column can have several user controls. Now I want to set width of user controls to expand as much as possible to stretch for width of listbox control. Is there some way to do this? If I set fixed width of user controls, it could leave some area blank on UI or horizontal scroll in listbox may appear. If I set "Auto" width of user control, there could be some unused space in UI. Is there any way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`HorizontalAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx) of your usercontrols to [`System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.horizontalalignment.aspx). Note that you should leave your Width unset if you do this, as it takes precedence over HorizontalAlignment.

Comment: Control got expanded when I set horizontal content alignment to stretch, but width of control got so wide that width expanded more than container control's width and horizontal scroll bar started to appear. Is there any way such that width expands such that horizontal scrollbar does not appear to container control ie. listbox?

Comment: @manoj, you are going to have to post some XAML if you want an exact answer, without that people can only guess what is causing your issue. `Stretch` should fill the space allocated to the control, it shouldn't cause the parent to grow.